# magento display short descriptions in crossell

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a site which has one product to cross sell with every other product in the store. The nature of the product means that it would benefit from displaying the short description.

I've tried `<?php echo $this->getShortDescription(); ?>` which rendered no results.

Some research on lead me to: 
`<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductInfo()->getShortDescription()); ?>` which returned:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getShortDescription() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/coursepurchase/app/design/frontend/default/tefl/template/checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml on line 43

Anyone able to help with this at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getShortDescription()); ?>
```